# Does Hopper Deassembler decombile Mobile Substrate .Dylib files?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, objective-c++, cydia, cydia-substrate

Does Hopper Deassembler open Mobile Substrate .dylib files to read tweaks's code or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Hopper can disassemble dynamic libraries. They have nothing to do with Mobile Substrate/Cydia Substrate.